# ImportError: No module named sklearn (Python)

Tags: python, macos, scikit-learn

I wanna use scikit-learn. I have typed

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
pip3 install sklearn
```

to install it; but when i type

```
$ Python
>>> import sklearn
```

it returns

```
ImportError: No module named sklearn
```

I followed other tutorials, but it doesn't work. Furthermore, my enviroment returns this warning:

> If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
>   to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
>   `make` in the source directory.

What is the true code to type in the terminal? I tried to type `python setup.py install`in the terminal but it doesn't work

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure that pip and python are the same version.
For example if you run pip for python 2.7, it will install the package only in 2.7, and if your python command point to for example python 3.3 interpreter, it will not have that package

Comment: Whant to do if I want to use python2.7 ?

Comment: I think if you want to use python2.7, then you need to use pip2.7

Comment: I had this exact same problem. I was able to run `import sklearn` successfully in the python3 shell by first running `pip3 install --user sklearn`.

Comment: As a new Python user, I discovered that running the Python command is different to running the Python3 command.

Answer (score 10):

you dont have the package scikit-learn installed, try this if you are in a terminal linux :

```
sudo pip install scikit-learn
```

if you want to install the package within your code use

```
import os 
os.system('sudo pip install scikit-learn')
```

Comment: Are you sure that using `sudo` privileges is required to install a package?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
pip3 install scikit-learn
```

Comment: This worked for me. I was using `pip install sklearn` instead of `pip install scikit-learn`. Once I made the change and then imported I got no error. Why does this work? Is sklearn something different?

Answer (score 1):

Not only for this package but also for almost cases, please try using `python3 -m pip install sklearn` if `pip install sklearn` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you havent install sklearn, try this on your python terminal:

```
pip install sklearn
```

and proceed with your code

Comment: That gives me "SyntaxError: invalid syntax".

Comment: Try `python -m pip install scikit-learn`

Answer (score 0):

this may happen that you have multiple versions of python and pip, do the following:

check your python version by typing:

```
    python --version
```

for python 3.8, install sklearn using

```
    pip3.8 install sklearn
```

for python 3.7, install sklearn using

```
    pip3.7 install sklearn
```

for python 3.6, install sklearn using

```
    pip3.6 install sklearn
```

and so on ....

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, solved with the following steps:

check python version with command:

```
$ python --version
```

if version is python 2.7, use:

```
$ sudo pip2 install <package_name>
```

of if the python version 3 is installed, use pip3 instead of pip2