# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.decomposition'

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

i want to import PCA from sklearn.decomposition, but following error occurs: 
"**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.decomposition'**". (just import sklearn works)

Does someone know how i can solve this problem?

I have installed the packages in Anaconda (conda version : 4.8.3)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named sklearn (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36404042/importerror-no-module-named-sklearn-python)

Comment: Which sklearn version do you have?

Comment: @Peter probably not, if `import sklearn` works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your `scikit-learn` package version:

```
import sklearn
print (sklearn.__version__) # this causes the problem!
```

You can uninstall your current `scikit-learn`:

```
$ conda remove scikit-learn
```

then install the downgraded package instead:

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn=0.20
```

Answer (score 1):

If the module installed, uninstall and install Sklearn again.
`python -m pip install -U sklearn`.