# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.decomposition.pca'

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, deep-learning, pickle

the model i used was implementing using scikit-learn==0.18, i try to install it but it fails,so i install scikit-learn==1.2.1. however, this error keeping appears for me and i dont have any idea how to fix it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "run_DeepDDI.py", line 51, in <module>
preprocessing.calculate_pca(similarity_profile, pca_similarity_profile, pca_model)
File "/content/deepddi/deepddi/preprocessing.py", line 80, in calculate_pca
pca = cPickle.load(fid)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.decomposition.pca'
```

also,the model used cPickle and it is removed so i fix it as " import pickle as cPickle".
i dont know if that affects the code

Comment: Same Problem solve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62149948/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sklearn-decomposition

Answer (score 0):

**Make a New Python Virtual Environment and again install `scikit-learn` in your newly made Virtual Virtual .** I Hope, it will work properly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).