# No command works to download sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, pip, download

I am trying to install sklearn. I have tried all the commands of this post: [ImportError: No module named sklearn (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36404042/importerror-no-module-named-sklearn-python) but none of these works.

I get this:

```
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for details.
      WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.1.2 is available.
      You should consider upgrading via the '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

What can I do?

Comment: I know it sounds like bad advice but if you are using 3.9 or 3.10 would try downgrading python to maybe 3.6, 3.7 or 3.8 - sklearn tends to be picky this way. In general, you should provide more details (are you in a virtual environment, using Jupyter or anything like that, what is the  full output and the command you are typing).

Comment: What happens with `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade scikit-learn`?  you may need to use `sudo`, be root, be in a virtual environment, or use `pip`'s `--user` option.  You may want to upgrade `pip` as recommended, as well.

Comment: Then i get this error:  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/_5/p38_bflx54b4d489x762knt80000gn/T/pip-install-yPtHHZ/numpy/setup.py'"'"';

Comment: __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/_5/p38_bflx54b4d489x762knt80000gn/T/pip-install-yPtHHZ/numpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
       cwd: /private/var/folders/_5/p38_bflx54b4d489x762knt80000gn/T/pip-install-yPtHHZ/numpy

Comment: Complete output (10 lines):
  Running from numpy source directory.
  
  `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:
  
    - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
    - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                        files that aren't checked into the git repo)
  
  Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).
  
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for numpy

Comment: What is the above output for? git should not be involved here at all. This all looks very strange in the last two comments. Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: I have written the command at the terminal, I am using jupyter lab.

Comment: I would recommend that you create a virtual environment for your project and then do a clean install (pip or conda) of the packages you need in your virtual environment. I do see where that weird clean command is in your previous note - but no idea what that is all about really.

Comment: If you execute `!pip install -U scikit-learn` in a `jupyterlab` cell, what happens?

Comment: This is what I get then: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
install: illegal option -- U
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 file2
       install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
       install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...

Comment: 1) what OS are you using? What version of python are you using? 2) Have you tried creating a new virtual environment and doing a fresh installation of all your project dependencies? 3) You probably need to post more of that full output .. maybe in your question or provide link to a github gist. Its hard to evaluate these snippets of error output. Clearly everything is very messed up - I would always try to start over completely in a case like this - even uninstalling and reinstalling python is not out of the question.